# Check first radio button with JQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, checked

I would like to check the first radio button of each group. But there are some radio button that are disabled, so the script should ignore them and go to next non-disabled button.

I wrote something like this but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($("input['radio']).is(':disabled'))
    {  
        $(this).attr('checked', false );
    }
else
    {
        $(this).attr('checked', true );
    }
});
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: **Or**, @Haim, `input:radio`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If your buttons are grouped by their name attribute, try:

```
$("input:radio[name=groupName][disabled=false]:first").attr('checked', true);
```

If they are grouped by a parent container, then:

```
$("#parentId input:radio[disabled=false]:first").attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: If you want the change event to fire, do `.click()` instead

Comment: It works. But I also need to trigger the change event once setting true.

Comment: I tried '.click()' as by @Yarin, but not worked. But I got it. To trigger 'change' event once setting true, $("input:radio[name=groupName]).trigger("change"); works perfectly.

Answer (score 18):

```
$("input:radio[name=groupX]:not(:disabled):first")
```

This should give you the first non-disabled radio-button from a group...

Answer (score 8):

The below does what you want:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    $('input:radio:first-child').attr('checked',true);
  }
  );
```

Demo at: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ofaga3/).

Comment: Although, to be fair, both @Šime and @rahul provide for sensible sanity-checks.

Comment: $('input:radio:first-child') selects the first radio button from any radio group in your page.

Answer (score 5):

I tested the first answer and it doesn't resolve it. I had to use the following sentence:

```
jQuery("input:radio[name=groupName]:visible")[0].checked=true;
```

This check the first visible radio button with name = groupName

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="radio" name="r1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="r1"><br>
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="r2"><br>
<input type="radio" name="r2"><br>
<input type="radio" name="r2"><br>

<script>
$(function(){
    //removed duplicates form the following array
    $(jQuery.unique(
        //create an array with the names of the groups
        $('INPUT:radio')
            .map(function(i,e){
                return $(e).attr('name') }
            ).get()
    ))
    //interate the array (array with unique names of groups)
    .each(function(i,e){
        //make the first radio-button of each group checked
        $('INPUT:radio[name="'+e+'"]:visible:first')
            .attr('checked','checked');
    });
});
</script>
```

jsfiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/v4auT/

Answer (score 2):

A little upgrade for 2020. The official documentation suggests the use of "first()" and "prop()"

```js
$("input[name='groupName'][disabled=false]").first().prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 $("input:radio:not(:disabled)").attr("checked", true);
```

To check the first radio button only in a group you can

```
 $("parentelement input:radio:not(:disabled):first-child").attr("checked", true);
```

Comment: I believe the OP meant "group" as in "all radio buttons that share the same name attribute"

Answer (score 1):

This makes the first radio checked by default

```
jQuery("input:radio[name=groupName]").first().click()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've the class and you don't bother about disabled items, just do this

```
$(".className").first().click();
```

Or simply

```
$(".className").first().prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Use .click(); to make sure that the selected dot is also visible otherwise prop('checked',true) will not shift the dot

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.choose_site input:radio').attr('checked',false); //Unchecked All
$('.choose_site input:radio').first().prop("checked", true); // Checked First
```