# how to set first radio button checked in asp inside repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radio-button, repeater

[Check first radio button with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977699/check-first-radio-button-with-jquery)

hi,
I have gone through this link above it is working fine but I have asp:RadioButton that too inside repeater control so want to checked the first radio button. the answer in above link is working fine for normal html but not for asp:radiobutton type, kindly help,
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't posted your code it's a bit of a guess but here how I would do this:

The RadioButton could be coded like this:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb" Checked='<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? true : false %>' runat="server"/>
```

This would check the first RadioButton the Repeater puts out.

Hope this helps.